# SQL JOIN Returning no values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am working with 3 tables with the following Names and columns:

```
*Table 1*
**Users**
UserID   UserName     UserTypeNumber
1          John           1N
2          Mary           1N
3          Doe            1N
4          Sullivan       2N
5          Sally          1N
**Key = UserID**

*Table 2*
**MobileUsers**
Userid   MobileAccess  
1          Yes           
2          Yes           
3          Yes           
4          Yes
5          No
**Key = UserID**



*Table 3*
**PanCards**
UserID   CARD_NUMBER                    
3          2222           
4          3333
5          1111
```

**Key = UserID**

Explanation:

- Every user is available in both **Users** and **MobileUsers** table
  However, not all users are present in **PanCards** table. This is
  because only users that have been assigned a Card appears in the
  **PanCards** table. In this case **Doe with UserID=3** and **Sullivan with UserID=4** have a card, hence they appear in **PanCards** table

Problem:

- What I want to achieve is to filter out the users from
  **MobileUsers** table that have **MobileAccess** equivalent to **Yes** and thier  **UserTypeNumber** equivalent to **1N** in the **Users** table but are not present in the **PanCards** table.

What I have so far is the below **SQL Query**:

```
SELECT MobileUsers.Userid, MobileUsers.MobileAccess
FROM MobileUsers
INNER JOIN Users
ON MobileUsers.Userid = Users.UserID
INNER JOIN PanCards
ON Users.UserID = PanCards.UserID
WHERE MobileUsers.MobileAccess = 'Yes'
AND
Users.UserTypeID = '1N' 
AND 
MobileUsers.Userid NOT IN
(SELECT PanCards.UserID FROM PanCards)
```

Result  is an Empty table

```
Userid   MobileAccess
```

However what i want is to have the below result returned:

```
Userid   MobileAccess  
1          Yes           
2          Yes
```

How do i fix this and get the correct results please ?

Comment: You're doing an INNER JOIN with PanCards, that means there must be a row in that table. Remove that join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `JOIN`, then use a `LEFT JOIN` for `PanCards` and check for no matches:

```
SELECT mu.*
FROM MobileUsers mu JOIN
     Users u
     ON mu.Userid = u.UserID LEFT JOIN
     PanCards pc
     ON pc.UserID = mu.UserID
WHERE mu.MobileAccess = 'Yes' AND
      u.UserTypeID = '1N' AND
      pc.UserID IS NULL;
```

I think your query would work without the join to `PanCards`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you very much . It's exaclty what i am looking for, it works.

Comment: @Hamza . . . Glad I could help.  Not certain why someone decided to downvote, though.  Probably the same person who downvoted your question (which certainly is not appropriate).

Comment: Am not sure why they down voted either. But I have accepted your answer. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH NotPan -- First get users that are not in the PanCards table
AS 
(
select * from Users as u
where u.userid not in (select userid from PanCards)
)
-- Easy from here
select * from NotPan as n
inner join mobileUsers m on m.userid = n.userid
inner join Users as u on n.userid = u.userid
WHERE m.MobileAccess = 'Yes' and u.UserTypeNumber = '1N'
```

Comment: Will probably do the job, but much more complex than a regular LEFT join with null check. I really don't see any reason to do this this way...